# Spark : cleaner way to build Dataset out of Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to create an API which looks like this

```
public Dataset<Row> getDataFromKafka(SparkContext sc, String topic, StructType schema);
```

here

`topic` - is Kafka topic name from which the data is going to be consumed.

`schema` - is schema information for Dataset

so my function contains following code :

```
    JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(javaSparkContext, Durations.milliseconds(2000L));
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            jsc, String.class, String.class,
            StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaConsumerConfig(), topics
    );
    Dataset<Row> dataSet = sqlContext.createDataFrame(javaSparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema);
    DataSetHolder holder = new DataSetHolder(dataSet);
    LongAccumulator stopStreaming = sc.longAccumulator("stop");
    directStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        RDD<Row> rows = rdd.values().map(value -> {
            //get type of message from value
            Row row = null;
            if (END == msg) {
                stopStreaming.add(1);
                row = null;
            } else {
                row = new GenericRow(/*row data created from values*/);
            }
            return row;
        }).filter(row -> row != null).rdd();
        holder.union(sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema));
        holder.get().count();
    });
    jsc.start();
    //stop stream if stopStreaming value is greater than 0 its spawned as new thread.
    return holder.get();
```

Here `DatasetHolder` is a wrapper `class` around `Dataset` to combine the result of all the `rdds`.

```
class DataSetHolder {
        private Dataset<Row> df = null;

        public DataSetHolder(Dataset<Row> df) {
            this.df = df;
        }

        public void union(Dataset<Row> frame) {
            this.df = df.union(frame);
        }

        public Dataset<Row> get() {
            return df;
        }
    }
```

This doesn't looks good at all but I had to do it. I am wondering what is the good way to do it. Or is there any provision for this by Spark?

## Update

So after consuming all the data from stream i.e. from kafka topic, we create a dataframe out of it so that the data analyst can register it as a temp table and can fire any query to get the meaningful result.

Comment: Perhaps if you wrote a little note on what exactly it is that you are trying to do. Why do you need to convert your stream to a DataSet?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I have included usecase